# Proof of Trigonometric Equation with using Complex Numbers

Tags: trigonometry

Prove this identity without using complex numbers: $$P(z, t) = A \cos(ωt -Bz + θ_1) + D \cos(ωt -Bz + θ_2) = C \cos(ωt -Bz + θ_{total})$$
Where $C = \sqrt{(A)^2 + (D)^2 +2AD\cos(θ_1 - θ_2)}$ and $$θ_{total} =  \tan ^{ - 1} \frac {A\sin(θ_1) + D\sin(θ_2)}{A\cos(θ_1) + D\cos(θ_2)}$$

Using the trigonometric identities, I get add the two, but I cannot simplify them to get the correct answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try expanding the right using $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$.  Also, use \cos and \sin for clarity.

Comment: Don't you mean $θ_{total} =  \arctan \dfrac{ (Asin(θ_1) + Dsin(θ_2))}{(Acos(θ_1) + Dcos(θ_2))}$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, yes I just edited it.

Comment: @SimpleArt, this is what you get when you expand it out:   $\cos(wt) [ \cos(Bz)[A \cos(θ_1)  + D \cos(θ_2)] +  \sin(Bz) [A \sin(θ_1)  + D \sin(θ_2)]]
\sin(wt) [ \sin(Bz)[A \cos(θ_1)   + D \cos(θ_2)] - \cos(Bz) [ A \sin(θ_1)  + D \sin(θ_2)]]$, but now what do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick outline which you can complete for yourself

1. For simplicity, write $x=\omega t-Bz$
2. Expand both sides using the compound angle formula for $\cos(A+B)$
3. Compare coefficients of $\cos x$ and of $\sin x$
4. Divide these equations to get the required form for $\tan \theta_{total}$
5. Square and add the equations to get the required form for $C^2$